# Flutter decrease space between 2 CheckboxListTiles?

Tags: flutter, mobile-development

Is there a way to decrease spacing between 2 checkbox list tiles (rows)? I dont't want to remove padding, it doesn't help me at all.

I have this:

[image]

But I want to get this:

[image]

```
                     child: ListView.builder(
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: 5,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        int starValue = index;
                        return CheckboxListTile(
                          value: _starValues[index],
                          title: Row(
                            children: List.generate(5, (i) {
                              return Icon(
                               ...
                              );
                            }),
                          ),
                          onChanged: ...
                        );
                      }),
```

Comment: why not create custom widget instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this documentation the space look not as big yours: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CheckboxListTile-class.html

but for the `ListTile` widget, you can modify the space by:

```
CheckboxListTile(
 dense: true
 // if it still too big then apply the visual density
 visualDensity: VisualDensity(vertical: -4),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a value to the `contentPadding` property of the `CheckboxListTile`.

```
return CheckboxListTile(
  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
```

or you can **create** your **custom** list tile widget

```
class CustomCheckbox extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onChanged;
  final int count;
  final bool value;
  const CustomCheckbox({super.key, required this.onChanged, required this.count, required this.value});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: ..., // Decorate if you want
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: onChanged, // This is your onChanged function
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0), //You can add checkbox padding or...
              child: Checkbox(onChanged:null,
              value: value),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 5), //... you can add gap between checkbox and stars
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                children: List.generate(count, (index) {
                  return Icon(
                               ...
                              );
                } ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.